# The type X cannot be used as type parameter T in the generic type Y

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, covariance

I don't see what is wrong with the following code, or how I can fix it. (Maybe I am misunderstanding generic types.)

```cs
class X<I>
   where I : ISomeInterface
{ }

class Y<T>
   where T : X<ISomeInterface>
{ }

class Z<I>
   where I : ISomeInterface
{
   Y<X<I>> AData { get; } // What compiler does not like
   Y<X<ISomeInterface>> BData { get; } // What compiler likes
}
```

Compiler complains that it cannot use `X<I>` as type parameter `T` in the generic type `Y<T>`.

Comment: Where is your code that calls this code / uses it?

Comment: [Can't reproduce this.](https://rextester.com/UYOV92427)

Comment: @ZoharPeled my mistake, please check the updated code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [working solution](https://rextester.com/SFQW76687)

```
interface ISomeInterface {}

class X<I>
   where I : ISomeInterface
{ }

class Y<T, I>
   where T : X<I>
   where I : ISomeInterface
{ }

class Z<I>
   where I : ISomeInterface
{
   Y<X<I>, I> MyOtherData { get; set; }
   Y<X<ISomeInterface>, ISomeInterface> MyData { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the additional generic parameter `I` and constraints I have added to the definition of type `Y`.

Your initial definition of `Y` is too restrictive. C# makes a difference between `ISomeInterface` and any type implementing `ISomeInterface`.

**Why is it so ?**

The .NET compiler has a special way of handing generic types. For each generic type the compiler will create a separate type based on the generic type arguments, which is instead used during runtime. For example `List<int>` and `List<string>` will be completely different types, all exhibiting the behaviours defined by the `List<_>` generic type, but with the actual type `int` or `string` baked into the concrete type generated by the compiler.

When you define `class Y<T> where T : X<ISomeInterface>` you "seal" the generic parameter of `X` to be `ISomeInterface`. The compiler will accept any type inheriting `X<ISomeInterface>` but not `X<SomethingElse>` even if `SomethingElse` is itself an implementation of `ISomeInterface`. This is because the fragment `where T : X<ISomeInterface>` causes the `ISomeInterface` to be "baked in" within the type definition of `Y<T>`. That behaviour is expected and is a side effect of how generics are compiled to actual code. For the same reason one cannot do the following:

```
List<object> x = new List<string>();
```

even though the type `string` inherits from `object`.